# flatmap a stream of a collection to a stream of its elements

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a stream of a sequence of events and want to flatmap it to a stream of the events.

I have problems with the syntax of the flatMap function

```
val stream = DataStream[Seq[Event]]

stream.flatMap(???)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: `stream.flatMap(identity)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at the examples that come with Flink, such as this [wordcount application](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/streaming/scala/examples/wordcount/WordCount.scala):

```
val counts: DataStream[(String, Int)] = text
  // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
  .flatMap(_.toLowerCase.split("\\W+"))
  .filter(_.nonEmpty)
  .map((_, 1))
  // group by the tuple field "0" and sum up tuple field "1"
  .keyBy(0)
  .sum(1)
```

The [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/stream/operators/#datastream-transformations) also has helpful code snippets in scala (and java).