# How to create a stream of objects inside a collection of a different collection

Tags: java, junit, java-stream, junit5

I am creating an ArrayList of an array and then returning the data in the form of a Stream from the method. But I need a stream of the objects inside the array. I believe I need to use [flatMap()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476199/flatmap-a-stream-of-a-collection-to-a-stream-of-its-elements) but what I have is not working for me, whereas when I `return Stream.of(Arguments.of(kt,r,expectedPoints));` It works, and I see the Objects correctly in my unit test.

```
class KdTreeTest {
    static class KdTreeArgumentsProvider implements ArgumentsProvider {
        final static File folder = new File("src/main/resources/kdtests/");
        KdTree kt = new KdTree();
        RectHV r = new RectHV(0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6);
        Point2D p1 = new Point2D(0.1, 0.2);
        Point2D p2 = new Point2D(0.8, 0.9);
        Point2D[] expectedPoints = {p1, p2};

        @Override
        public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
            Object[] instanceData = new Object[3];
            List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>();
            for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
                String fileName = fileEntry.getName().toUpperCase();
                if (fileName.endsWith(".TXT")) {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileEntry);
                    kt = new KdTree();
                    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                        double x = scanner.nextDouble();
                        double y = scanner.nextDouble();
                        Point2D p = new Point2D(x, y);
                        kt.insert(p);
                    }
                    instanceData[0] = kt;
                    instanceData[1] = r;
                    instanceData[2] = expectedPoints;
                    l.add(instanceData);
                }
            }
            return Stream.of(Arguments.of((l.stream().flatMap(x->Stream.of("x[0]","x[1]","x[2]")))));
        }
    }

    @DisplayName("should create a rectangle with the given coordinates and test KdTree's range() function")
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index}=> kt={0},r={1},expectedPoints={2}")
    @ArgumentsSource(KdTreeArgumentsProvider.class)
    void range(KdTree kt, RectHV r, Point2D[] expectedPoints) {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(kt.range(r));
    }
}
```

I think I can just put everything in an Object[] from the beginning, but just our of curiosity is there a way to do this with Stream methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly what you're trying to do, then you need to make two changes:

1. Change the type of `l` from `List<Object>` to `List<Object[]>`:

   ```
   List<Object[]> l = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. Change the return statement to:

   ```
   return l.stream()
           .map(Arguments::of);
   ```

Unpacking this:

1. `l.stream` produces a `Stream<Object[]>` from `l`
2. `map(Arguments::of)` calls `Arguments.of` on each array in the stream, creating an `Arguments` object with three entries, matching the arguments of the `range` method

You don't want to flatten the array into the stream, because that would result in a stream of `Arguments` objects with a single element.